# How to implement black/white table in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to make small WPF project with a table that should not have text value in cells, but change background color depending on the value. The table should look like:

[image: 1]

Which a control I should use and how to change color(for this control) by indexes of row and column.

I have already written some code, but it does not work.

```
<Grid Name="Grid">
    <DataGrid Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  HeadersVisibility="None" SelectionUnit="Cell">

        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>

 public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    [Reactive]
    public DataView DataView { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var array = new int[2, 2] { { 1, 0 }, { 1, 0 } };
        var rows = array.GetLength(0);
        var columns = array.GetLength(1);

        var t = new DataTable();
        for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        {
            t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
        }

        for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            var newRow = t.NewRow();
            for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++)
            {
                newRow[c] = new MyCell() {Value = array[r, c] == 1};
            }
            t.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
        DataView = t.DefaultView;
    }
}

 public class MyCell
    {
        public bool Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is almost correct. But CellStyle has DataGrid's DataContext in it's DataContext, so you binging your Trigger not to individual cell, but to entire viewmodel. You need to create DataTemplate for ItemTemplate and inside it you can use DataContext as a MyCell.